# Can we download Magento 2 Enterprise Edition for free?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise-2

I want to know whether we can download Magento 2 EE for free for development purpose?

Is it possible, please give me a link to download it.

Looking forward your reply.

Comment: Magento Enterprise edition is not free as community edition you have to purchase it. Or you need to be Magento partner to be able to access the code. It can not be downloaded as free.
Download it from https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no and no link exists

You must have an active Magento Commerce Cloud user license to even setup Commerce Cloud on docker